# "Smart quotes" in Sublime Text 2 with LaTeXTools

Tags: latex, sublimetext2

I've recently migrated my LaTeX-authoring from TeXWorks to Sublime Text 2, and one feature which I'm really missing is the ability to type "regular quotes", (using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> on my Swedish keyboard, yielding `"quoted text"`) and having the editor automatically convert them to the correct way of quoting in LaTeX, which is ``` ``quoted text'' ``` while I'm typing.

I've tried to look for a way to do this in ST2, but most of what I find is related to escaping quotes in strings automatically, which is not what I'm after.

Is there a way to get this functionality in ST2?

Comment: Note: ST2 hightlights `"quoted text"` with a red background, indicating that it's aware that the syntax is wrong, but it doesn't actually change my input.

Comment: You could try writing a simple plugin that searches for the `invalid.illegal.string.quoted.double.latex` selector. From there you should be able to substitute the first/last characters with the proper quotes. Perhaps use the on_modified listener and only try to change the current line. Anyways, just some ideas, not sure what the best way to do it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be able to make Sublime Text 2 give quotes a once-over you're finished writing them, but since that would probably involve writing a complicated plugin, why not remap the `"` key to insert the correct characters instead?

It's possible to add custom key bindings which mimic the default automatic `"` pairing but instead insert LaTeX quotes where appropriate. Add these lines (sourced from `Preferences -> Key Bindings – Default`, lines 272–293) to your `Preferences -> Key Bindings – User` file:

```
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "``$0''"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[\"a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double", "match_all": true }
    ]
},

{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "``${0:$SELECTION}''"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
    ]
},

{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "words", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^''", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

The first chunk of code overwrites Sublime Text's default quote-pairing and adapts it for LaTeX-styled quotes. When you type a `"` within a LaTeX file, as long as it's in a location that would normally insert a set of double quotes, you'll get this:

```
``|''
```

The second section replaces the default functionality for automatically enclosing selected text with quotes. In a LaTeX file, selecting text and then pressing `"` will result in this:

```
``This is the text you selected|''
```

The final re-binding skips over ending quotes (`''`) when you press `"` while the caret is adjacent to them. That is, when you press `"` here:

```
``Sublime Text is the best!|''
```

The caret will move outside of the quotes, like this:

```
``Sublime Text is the best!''|
```

Comment: I'm not able to try this out at the moment, but it looks fantastic. I'll try it out on Monday and get back with the results.

Comment: I've been able to test this now, and it works precisely as I want it too. If I could upvote this more than once, I would!

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Latexing package](http://www.latexing.com/) it doesn't list this as a feature but it automatically converts `"` to ``` ``|'' ``` with the caret in the center ready for your quoted text. Pressing `"` will then move the caret past the closing ``` ``''| ```.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way I see is using a snippet. This one will work -

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
``${1:this}''
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>lq</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.tex.latex</scope>
</snippet>
```

Save this as `latex-quote.sublime-snippet` in `Packages > User` under ST2's directory. Then at any point you want to use the quotes, just write `lq`(I named it from LaTeX quote) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Then I can just as well write `` (two backticks), which ST2 completes to ``'' (two backticks followed by two single quotes) with the cursor in the middle - I was hoping to not have to change the keyboard combinations that by now are hard-wired in my fingers... EDIT: the formatting was messed up, tried to clarify.